# How can I set a default value for a TimeSpan setting in VIsual Studio to >=24 hours?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, timespan

In the visual studio settings box it is possible to create a setting of type TimeSpan. I'm trying to make it default to >=24 hours. The annoying behaviour is that:

`23:00:00` equates to 23 hours (same as TimeSpan.Parse)

`24:00:00` equates to 768 hours (= 24 days) (same as TimeSpan.Parse)

If I enter `1:0:0:0` visual studio changes this value to 1.0:0:0 which equates to 1 hour (TimeSpan.Parse equates this to 24 hours which is what I want)

The TimeSpan type is nice because it allows type safety to be enforced and the user is able to edit a nicer looking representation (albeit possibly more confusing due to the `23:00:00`/`24:00:00` behaviour which is somewhat counterintuitive to me), but I can't see how  to do this and allow >= 24 hour TimeSpans

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking at wrong property - `Hours` is hours of the day, while you seem to be interested in `TotalHours`. I.e. you sample give 24 hours (1 day) as expected:

```
TimeSpan.Parse("1.00:00:00").TotalHours == 24
TimeSpan.Parse("2.01:00:00").TotalHours == 49
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not do your own parsing and then call `TimeSpan` constructor.  An overload exists for day, hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds.

Comment: You can also store the TimeSpan as a string, then parse into a TimeSpan.